# RMySQL cannot insert new data

Tags: r, rmysql

I try to insert new data to MySQL using RMySQL. Only for this case I always fail and always get the same warning message. The message was:

```
Warning message:
In value[[3L]](cond) : corrupt resultSet, missing fieldDescription
```

Although it just a warning, I never find my data show on MySQL.

Complete code and warning message shown as below:

[image: RMySQL Warning Message]

Please advise any solution.

Comment: Please do not paste an image of code and error! It's not hard to copy the text from the R or RStudio console, paste them in here, and then prefix every row with four spaces (to format as code ... SO formatting really could use triple-backticks from markdown).

Comment: Since nothing else here is known, you need to investigate this yourself. I suggest you first confirm that the database table definition (schema) is what you need and intend. Second, ensure the `criteo` here doesn't contain unsupported data types. For more, we likely need more info, including versions of your OS, R, `RMySQL` and `DBI` packages, and of the MySQL server itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bxWUN.png)

Oh, Please, don't forget to un-comment library(RMySQL) [ line : 1 ].
&
Please, add query in lieu of "select age from Customers". [ line : 9 ].
:)

Maybe, it'll works fine.

[ Sorry, for my bad English. ]